# Django Foreign Key

Tags: python, django

У меня есть одна категория. Как я могу получить все товары, которые связаны с этой категорией в шаблоне? Типа вот так:

```html
{% for category in categories %}
    {{ category.products }}
{% endfor %}
```

Просто можно обратиться наоборот вот я и подумал, а как по другому?
Можно обраться вот так:

```
{% for product in products %}
    {{ product.category }}
{% endfor %}
```

models.py

```py
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, verbose_name='Категория')
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, unique=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='categories/img/', verbose_name='Фотография')


class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=99, blank=True, verbose_name='Название')
    price = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Цена')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/img/', verbose_name='Фотография')
    availability = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True, verbose_name='Наличие')
    popular = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True, verbose_name='Популярность товара')
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, verbose_name='Категория')
```

Comment: А сериализаторы вы используете?

Comment: Нет, не использую

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете в ForeignKey использовать `related_name` аргумент. Он позволит обращаться к связанным данным.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    pass

class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, ... related_name='products')
```

И теперь в вашем шаблоне можно получить все продукты, используя примерно такой код:

```
{% for category in categories %}
    {% for product in category.products.all %}
        {{ product.title }}
        ...
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Вот [тут подробнее можно узнать](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) об этом

Answer (score 0):

Category.objects.filter(ну и тут ваш код) - это даст какие-то категории.
Если вы хотите продукты, вам нужно `Product.objects.filter(category=[тут pk категории])`

Comment: А если я получу категории, то я могу в шаблоне сделать например вот так? `{% for cat in categories%} cat.products {% endfor %}` Мне надо, чтобы я из шаблона мог как-то подключиться к товарам

Comment: Получается, вы хотите список категорий с полем, содержащим массив продуктов этой категории?